# MSAL/ADAL support for new/old Azure python SDK modules

Tags: azure, adal, azure-ad-msal

Our application start with ADAL authentication with Azure python SDK 2.0.0.
Now that I start to upgrade `azure.mgmt.servicebus` to 6.0.0, I found exception while using the ADAL credential.

```
creatednamespace = servicebus_client.namespaces.begin_create_or_update(resource_group_name, namespace_name, namespaceparameter).result()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/mgmt/servicebus/operations/_namespaces_operations.py", line 563, in begin_create_or_update
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/mgmt/servicebus/operations/_namespaces_operations.py", line 502, in _create_or_update_initial
    pipeline_response = self._client._pipeline.run(request, stream=False, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 211, in run
    return first_node.send(pipeline_request)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/mgmt/core/policies/_base.py", line 47, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_redirect.py", line 157, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_retry.py", line 436, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 69, in send
    _await_result(self._policy.on_request, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_tools.py", line 29, in await_result
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_authentication.py", line 93, in on_request
    self._token = self._credential.get_token(*self._scopes)
```

I read Azure documentation that new features will require MSAL or azure.identity and I used azure.identy and it worked.
Now the question is we have a mix of old and new Azure SDK packages, which authentication shall we follow?  I tried the old package with azure.identity, it seems still working. But I am not sure if there is any issue that I might not be aware of.
Hope we can get a clear Azure authentication guide to support both old and new python SDK packages.

Answer (score 0):

The package `azure.identity` provides a set of credential classes for use with Azure SDK clients which support Azure Active Directory (AAD) token authentication. Mow Microsoft suggests customers use the package to do auth with other Azure python sdks. But please note that it does not support all azure packages. If the package does not use `azure.core`, we use it to do auth, we will face error. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate?tabs=cmd#when-does-authentication-and-authorization-occur) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-library-package-index#libraries-using-azurecore).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.  Seems we need to have two set of authentication support depending on which package we use and whether the package use azure.core or not. It is a bit of inconvenient but I guess we just have to live with it.

Comment: I already added to the answer but seems it is now showing up some how.